# ui-grid dropdown editor with complex json object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using the angular-ui-grid to make an editable grid and have looked over the tutorial here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

Unlike the example where the options are simple structures like gender male/female, I am trying to bind a complex JSON object in my model.  All of the examples I have found are binding to a simple String or Integer object.

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4VVIeToIvNALwcPFhP46?p=preview) on Plunker (this code was first taken from the tutorial and then slightly modified to show the problem I am facing):

The core of it is in the columnDef config for the data grid.

```
{ 
    name: 'product', 
    field: 'product.name',
    enableCellEdit: true, 
    editType: 'dropdown', 
    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.products,
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'name',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'name'
}
```

I have tried changing the values for field and editDropdownIdLabel to a variety of options to no avail. If you look at the 3 console.log lines 51-53 in the sample code you will see that as you change the product selected the name changes but the ID stays the same.  I want to be able to pass the whole product object to the backend when ultimately saving changes made in this grid.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quite similar issue and I found a solution which worked for me:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2808 
mltroutt's comment on Feb 20 - a generic filter.

based on that, in your pluncker I tried that in the following way:
your product column should be look like this:

```
name: 'product', 
    field: 'product.id',
    cellFilter: "griddropdown:editDropdownOptionsArray:editDropdownIdLabel:editDropdownValueLabel:row.entity.product.name",
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'name',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.products
```

then after your controller, you have to insert a filter like this:

```
.filter('griddropdown', function () {
    return function (input, map, idField, valueField, initial) {
        if (typeof map !== "undefined") {
            for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
                if (map[i][idField] == input) {
                    return map[i][valueField];
                }
            }
        } else if (initial) {
            return initial;
        }
        return input;
    };
})
```

Comment: How check change in dropdown selection..?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using the same `product` objects in your `data` array and the `editDropdownOptionsArray` array and getting the whole `product` structure placed into your `data` structure when a new one is selected.  First, in the `columnDef` change the field to just `product` instead of `product.name`, change the `editDropdownIdLabel` to `ref` (explained in the next step), and add a `cellTemplate` as shown.

```
field: 'product',
editDropdownIdLabel: 'ref',
cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity.product.name}}</div>'
```

Second, create a self-referencing field `ref` inside each `product` so that you can return that instead of just `id` when a selection is made.  Also, replace the `product` inside your `data` with a reference to the actual `product` object.

```
let prods = {};
angular.forEach($scope.products, (product) => {
  prods[product.id] = product;  // hash for products by id
  product.ref = product;        // self reference
});
angular.forEach(data, (person) => {
  person.product = prods[person.product.id];
});
```

Now, when an item is selected everything is kept in sync.  Also, you are (arguably) actually using the grid and select tools as intended and not creating filters, watchers, etc., etc. to try to fix things up.

Now, if ui-grid had an option (like maybe the default) where the object in the options array would be returned instead of requiring a field of the object to be returned this would be a lot easier and would not create circular data structures.  Maybe `editDropdownIdLabel: ''` or `'self'` or `null`?  Or, maybe somebody knows of a better way to get the reference.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wjtuwgvZYIxWpkenJS7a?p=preview and a simpler version based on the gender field example from @bagavathi - http://plnkr.co/edit/JJduek?p=preview

This solution does assume that your product data really is the same and can be shared but is probably a typical use case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableSorting: false,
            enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
            data: data,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                   name: 'product', 
                    field: 'productName',
                    enableCellEdit: true, 
                    editType: 'dropdown', 
                    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.products,
                    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
                    editDropdownIdLabel: 'name',
                    editDropdownValueLabel: 'name'
                }
            ],
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                //set gridApi on scope
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (colDef.name === 'product') {
                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
                            var prod = $scope.products[i];

                            if (prod.name === newValue) {
                                rowEntity.product = prod;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        calculateBOption(rowEntity);
                    }                        
                });
            }
```

}